# Starling - load SWF image(vector) into a Image

Tags: actionscript-3, swfloader, starling-framework

I'm trying to convert an old project of mine to use Starling for some extra performance.
I've come to a problem when I'm loading my SWFs and trying to display them.

Here is the code I used before: *(no Starling)*

```
private function swfLoaded(e:LoaderEvent):void {
    var spr:Sprite = new Sprite();
    spr = e.currentTarget.content;
    bitmapData.draw(spr ...);
}
```

The problem when I'm using Starling is that the currentTarget.content is a flash.display.displayObject.

```
cannot convert com.greensock.loading.display::ContentDisplay@90ffec1 to starling.display.Sprite
```

I want to find a way to "convert" the flash.display.displayObject into a starling Sprite.
I also want to be able to store the loaded swfs content into a array as a sprite.

*Thanks in advance,
Tompa*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting spr with a different value immediately after you create it, for one thing.

After you do the bitmapData.draw() call:

```
var tex:Texture = Texture.fromBitmapData(bitmapData, false, false);
```

The new texture can then be used to create a Starling Image sprite.